# Help me identify this Bullnose 75 plane

Tags: hand-tools, plane, tool-identification

I have just received this bullnose plane and I'm trying to identify it. I suppose its a record 75 plane, but i'm not sure about that. Someone can help me? Most of record 75 present different caps and bolts...
[image]

[image]

Comment: This might be a Record (a 075 in their numbering system) and the hex bolt could just be a replacement, not common but sometimes seen. It looks old enough, but if it is a 075 the lighter shade of blue and certain areas which are painted that were originally machined surfaces both strongly suggest it is of later production, possibly from after Irwin bought them out. The one place these would have been indelibly marked was a stamping on the iron, so check both sides (although it should be on the bevel side). Brand stampings are rarely obliterated by rust, but can be hidden by it.

Comment: Hi Graphus! Thanks for your contribution! I will try to remove the rust to see the stamping. Do you have any guess about the year of this model?

Comment: If it is a Record I'd hazard a guess of 80s or later, even though it looks older due to its condition. This guess is based on the colour which got lighter and lighter as the years progressed (with Irwin Record tools being almost sky blue now). I think I should mention that these planes aren't highly regarded! Even a well-made 75 or 075 from a good era when standards were still high shouldn't be expected to be a great performer.

Comment: Wow, someone told me that all 075 were made from 1932 to 1967. Thanks for this information!

Comment: Actually that's correct! At least as far as the Record-Planes.com site goes, and most of that is regarded as definitive. I forgot to check the production years for this and was going just by the colour. I'm wondering even more now whether this is a repainted something else.